# Checking if vendor is present in shopify cart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to find out if a vendor is present within my customers cart using Javascript like so:

```
$.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {

  var inArray = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    if (cart[i].vendor === 'example') {
      inArray = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  alert(inArray);

});
```

If I have a product in my cart from the vendor "example", my alert returns false. Can anyone shine a light on why?

If I do:

```
$.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {

  $.each(cart.items, function(index, cartItem) {
    alert('This product is ' + cartItem.vendor);
  });

});
```

I will get an alert with the vendor name for each item in the cart - I just cant seem to check if it exists.

I know I could use liquid to get this information fairly easily, but i'm wanting to restrict delivery days to the jQuery datepicker based on vendors in the cart and current time (on the users machine) so I'm having to use Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised your first script even runs. You should be iterating on cart.items not cart.

```
for(var i = 0; i< cart.items.length; i++){
    if(cart.items[i].vendor == 'example'){
        inArray = true; 
        break;
    }
}
```